# How to use Sioyek as the default pdf viewer in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, pdf

I want to be able to link to pdf files in spacemacs and open them with Sioyek.

This post: https://github.com/ahrm/sioyek/discussions/347 seems to almost solve my issue but I have no idea where to put the code he suggested.

Comment: The question needs to stand on its own, not requiring to follow a link. Please incorporate whatever info is needed to completely pose the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ahrm/sioyek/discussions/347#discussioncomment-3892630) sioyek has been added to `TeX-view-program-list-builtin` so that you only have to add "Sioyex" to `TeX-view-program-selection`. For that place the following in the body of `dotspacemacs/user-config` (search using `SPC j i` in your dotfile):

```lisp
  (with-eval-after-load 'tex
    (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Sioyek")))
```